# CSS/HTML CSS style sheet locking in changes and being unable to revert them?

Tags: html, css

I've been having a problem where my css style sheet isn't effecting my HTML page. After trying numerous attempts at getting it to work, I deleted the style sheet and rewrote it. To test I changed my background of my site to red. This worked.

However when I went to change other things (like font) nothing else would change. This includes the red background which won't go back to the original white. I deleted that style sheet again, put in a new style sheet with this code for background:

```
 body {
   background: #fafafa;
   color: #333333;
   margin-top: 5rem;
 }
```

But the background still won't change back. I restarted the server and Visual Studio Code but it just won't go back. This is the source on the html page which shows the color as not white:

```
body {   background: #bb3636;   color: #333333;   margin-top: 5rem; }
```

In summary, CSS/HTML wasn't allowing any changes, after deleting, CSS was working for about a minute but now has gone back to not allowing any changes. I'm using Firefox as browser and Visual Studio Code. I'm also importing from bootstrap with a custom style sheet with additional style info.

Comment: Add an !important after `background: #bb3636 !important`. Also, check developer tools to see if the changes appear

Comment: Are there any server-side chachers like `mod pagespeed` ? This can cause CSS / JS changes to not show until server-side cache is cleared ..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but still no changes

Comment: How do I check for mod pagespeed or clear my cache? I deleted my _pycache_ folder that gets generated but that hasn't done anything.

Comment: this can also be a client side caching issue. Try opening the page in incognito mode and check if it works...

Comment: Incognito Mode shows changes! Can someone explain why and how I clear the cache in non-incognito mode?

Answer (score 0):

Caching issue, as stated in the comments. Opened page through incognito mode to see changes had taken place there. Thanks for all the answers everyone.